# How to append a character using regex in rewrite rule?

Tags: regex

I have to rewrite a rule in which on the basis of a first char of a string i have to append a character in url.
For example :-

```
/us/en/products/collections/jewelery/bracelet.html  ---->    /content/us/en/products/collections/jewelery/b/bracelet.html

/au/en/products/collections/watches/reverso.html   ----->    /content/us/en/products/collections/watches/r/reverso.html

/us/en/products/collections/watches/hybrid.html   ------>    /content/us/en/products/collections/watches/h/hybrid.html
```

As you can see in above example on the basis of the last string(bracelet,reverso,hybrid). I'm appending the first character of string before it.

I have matched the last character occurrence after "/" using "(/([^/]+)$)" pattern but didn't find any way to extract first char and append it before this. Is it possible to this. If yes please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(?!content/)(.+)/([a-z])([\w-]*\.html)$ /content/$1/$2/$2$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for response. But it doesn't working properly . for last url i have replaced it & output is /content//us/en/products/collections/watches/h/ybrid.html . double "/" which can be resolve but it remove h from hrbrid.